# Dagger Hilt: Inject interface that inherits another interface

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have an app that implements MVP pattern and I want to simplify boilerplate code with Hilt. So far so good. The problem comes when I want to Inject a presenter that takes as a paramter a interface implementation of MyView, but I want to pass a implementation of an interface that inherits MyView because the presenter may be injected in diferent fragments with diferent MyView implementations

My presenter:

```
class BluetoothPresenter @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val  context: Context,
    private val view: MyView
) {
```

The presenter is injected in the Fragment:

```
class DevicesListFragment() : Fragment(), DevicesListMyView {

    @Inject
    lateinit var btPresenter: BluetoothPresenter
```

DevicesListView is a interface that inherits MyView interface

```
interface DevicesListView : MyView {
    fun onSearchDevicesStarted();
    fun searchDevicesFinished();
    fun onDeviceFound(device: BluetoothDevice)
}
```

MyView:

```
interface MyView {
    fun showError()
    fun showMessage()
}
```

My module that tells Hilt how to provide the MyView:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface MainModule {

    @Binds
    fun provideView(devicesListFragment: DevicesListView) : MyView

    @Binds
    fun provideDeviceView(devicesListFragment: DevicesListFragment) : DevicesListView

}
```

I get this error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property btPresenter has not been initialized
```

Thanks

Comment: So if I understand correct, your Interface "myView" is your fragment "DeviceListFragment" in this example?

Comment: Correct. And I ran into another error, when I inject the DeviceListFragment into the presenter as an implementation of myView I get "Found a dependency cycle", I understand why I get this error, I'm injecting the presenter into the fragment that injects the fragments as myView, that injects the fragment, and so on, but then I don't know how I'm supposed to inject the presenter in the fragment. Thanks

Comment: Well you can't. If you want to inject your fragment inside your Presenter, you can't inject the presenter into your fragment. You have to decide: Do you want to inject the fragment into the presenter and use it somewhere else or do you inject the presenter into the fragment but use another view?